# template does not exists not work even all thing correct

Tags: python, django, templates, project

i dont know where is my mistake that am sure my code is correct
view.py:

```
 from django.http import HttpResponse
 from .models import Task
 from django.template import loader
 from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index(request):
    list_task = Task.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('new2/index.html')
    context = {
        'list_task': list_task
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(request, context))
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Task(models.Model):


    Name_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Age_task = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

index.html:

```
 {% if list_task %}
        <ul>
             {% for i in list_task %}
             <li>
                 <a href="#">{{i.Name_task}}</a>
             </li>
             {% endfor %}
        </ul>

    {% else %}
    {% endif %}
```

urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from new2 import views

urlpatterns = (
    # path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

i tried this code in setting.py:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'todoapp')],
```

and this also for template location but still not works :

```
 'DIRS': [r'C:\Users\hajar\Downloads\new\new1\new2\template'],
```

the path for tamplate was:

```
C:\Users\hajar\Downloads\new\new1\new2\template\new2\index.html
```

any one can give me the solution 3 days actualy i tried with nothing

error :

context must be a dict rather than WSGIRequest.
and template not exist

thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem "*context must be a dict rather than WSGIRequest*", does not mean you load the wrong template, it means that you pass the context as a dictionary, instead of a [**`RequestContext`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#using-requestcontext), you should use:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Task
from django.template import loader, RequestContext
from django.template.response import TemplateResponse

def index(request):
    list_task = Task.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('new2/index.html')
    context = {
        'list_task': list_task
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(RequestContext(request, context)))
```

But you might want to use the [**`render(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead. This removes a lot of boilerplate code:

```
from .models import Task
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    list_task = Task.objects.all()
    context = {
        'list_task': list_task
    }
    return render(request, 'new2/index.html', context)
```

This will thus load the template, create a `RequestContext`, and wrap the rendered template in a `HttpResponse`.

Comment: i'v used it actually still not work , and in (template doesnot exist) i mean like if i delete the dire path from setting.py ,this error comes to me: template doesnot exist    < TemplateDoesNotExist at /new2/

new2/index.html

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/new2/
Django Version:  3.1.2

Comment: @HAbdullah: but you say that there are two errors: "*context must be a dict rather than WSGIRequest*". and "*template not exist*". In case the former happens, then it already has loaded the template. So likely at some point you configured the settings correctly. Did you set`APP_DIRS` to `True` in the settings?

Comment: @HAbdullah: normally the name of the directory is furthermore `templates` (with `s`), and in the app directory. So you should move it to the correct directory.

Comment: yes i did that and i dont knwo why still not work,disappointed maybe thers way here to share all th project file ! maybe u or any one can see and know where my mistake which is i cant see it till now

Answer (score 0):

How about trying to use render() instead and replace `'todoapp'` with `'templates'` like:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

and prints out the DIRS `TEMPLATES[0]['DIRS']` in setting.py...